# Phoenix Upgrade causes missing function clause for put_req_header

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I upgraded to Phoenix 1.1.0 recently and test code that used to pass is now throwing an error. The test code is:

```
  test "/api call with invalid unique_code gets an error code", %{conn: conn} do    

    conn = recycle(conn)
      |> put_req_header("unique_code", "123")
      |> put_req_header("domain", "cision.com")    

    conn = get conn, "/api/organizations/valid"
    assert conn.status == 500
  end
```

The error I'm getting now is:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Plug.Conn.put_req_header/3
     stacktrace:
       (plug) lib/plug/conn.ex:460: Plug.Conn.put_req_header(%Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Test.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{}, before_send: [], body_params: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :body_params}, cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}, halted: false, host: "www.example.com", method: "GET", owner: #PID<0.293.0>, params: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :params}, path_info: [], peer: {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 111317}, port: 80, private: %{phoenix_recycled: true, plug_skip_csrf_protection: true}, query_params: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :query_params}, query_string: "", remote_ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, req_cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}, req_headers: [], request_path: "/", resp_body: nil, resp_cookies: %{}, resp_headers: [{"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"}], scheme: :http, script_name: [], secret_key_base: nil, state: :unset, status: nil}, "unique_code", nil)
```

I tried to add a **import Plug.Conn** and **alias Plug.Conn** to the top of the file, but that didn't change anything. I'm a Phoenix/Elixir beginner so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace along side the code? It would help a lot if we knew *which* line was failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the stack trace, you are calling `put_req_header(%Conn{}, "unique_code", nil)`, where the value must always be a binary. I'm assuming your provided test case was a simplified version of the real thing, and that maybe you are calling `code.id` (which is nil)? Double check there.

Comment: Unfortunately the test case isn't simplified & is the real thing. I hadn't changed any of my code and just did the upgrade to Phoenix and Ecto. In the previous version of Phoenix/Ecto this test case & all of my other similar cases passed.

Comment: Your stack trace is showing `put_req_header(%Conn{}, "unique_code", nil)` so there is something we aren't seeing from the provided code. Can you provide your full, current test cases that produced this stack trace?

Comment: Actually you were correct. The test case I put in wasn't the one erroring on closer inspection of the errors. What was happening was that I wasn't using a changeset to do inserts and some information wasn't getting populated, but was nil instead.